# flask can not read static path and load Javascript files

Tags: javascript, python, flask

my app structure is

```
project/
       configuration/__init__.py
       core/
       static
             /app
                 /css
                 /img
                 /js/app.js
                 /lib/angular/angular.js
                 /partials
             index.html
```

My file `configuration/__init__.py` has something as

```
# setting up template directory
TEMPLATE_DIR = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), '../static/app')

app = Flask(__name__, template_folder=TEMPLATE_DIR, static_folder=TEMPLATE_DIR)
```

When I load the page `localhost/index.html`, I see javascript error as

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:5000/js/app.js 404 (NOT FOUND) home:8
GET http://127.0.0.1:5000/lib/angular/angular.js 404 (NOT FOUND) home:8
```

Even though I know that these files are there, I guess that static_folder is not able to find these files, what am I doing wrong here

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I fixed it by putting relative urls in `index.html`

**configuration/_*init*_.py**

```
# setting up template directory
ASSETS_DIR = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), '../static/app')

app = Flask(__name__, template_folder=ASSETS_DIR, static_folder=ASSETS_DIR)
```

**index.html**

```
  <script src="../app/lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="../app/js/app.js"></script>
```